# How to config NSURLSessionConfiguration into the NSObject class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession, nsobject

i want to get server response from `NSObject` when i m getting a response,it has return to viewController.as i implement on server call into `NSObject` class then i called to the `NSObject` method but before server response my `NSString` have been return as `null`.

```
 NSObject class :   

     @interface getServerCallClassMethod :
     NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate>
{
         NSString *ResponceStr; 
}
-(NSString *)getServerCall:(NSString *)mobleNo serverUrl:(NSString *)url;

     @end
```

implement part :

@implementation getServerCallClassMethod

```
-(NSString *)getServerCall:(NSString *)mobleNo serverUrl:(NSString *)url{    

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]; 
      NSURLSession *urlSession=[NSURLSession
         sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self
         delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
     NSURL *servrurl=[NSURL URLWithString:GetOTP]; 
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask=[urlSession
         dataTaskWithURL:servrurl completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,
         NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable
         connectionError)
        {  if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil){   
            ResponceStr=@"success"; } else{   ResponceStr=@"fail"; 
        }
       }];
         [dataTask resume]; 
     });
             return ResponceStr;
     } 
  In Vc : 
    getServerCallClassMethod  *GetServerCallMethod=[[getServerCallClassMethod alloc]init]; 

    NSString *valide=[GetServerCallMethod getServerCall:@"800000000" serverUrl:@"http://www.gg.com"]; NSLog(@"valide");
```

Comment: if want to get server response try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37086586/4003548)

Comment: but i wanna how to get from NSObject class because i don't wanna override as same code to  all the place .if i written one NSObject server method  then i want to call the server method from any class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

**In interface file**

```
@interface APISession : NSURLSession <NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionDataDelegate,NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

+(void)apiCallSharedSessionGet:(NSString *)strURL withCompletionHandlar:(void (^) (NSString *response, NSError *error, int status)) completionBlock;
```

**In Implementation file**

```
@implementation APISession



+(void)apiCallSharedSessionGet:(NSString *)strURL withCompletionHandlar:(void (^) (NSString *response, NSError *error, int status)) completionBlock
{


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

   __block NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error!=nil)
        {
            completionBlock(nil,error,0);
            [task suspend];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
            completionBlock(requestReply,error,1);
            [task suspend];
        }

    }];
 [task resume];

}
```

Comment: @PiyushPatel May I ask question? I didn't see u declare the "tack" in the code. I run your code appear a issues that it show "use of undeclared identifier 'task'"...may you help me?

Comment: Thanks, this is a beautiful solution you updated. But may I know why need to task suspend after completionHandler? Usually I saw other demo are only task resume.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get response from `NSURLSessionDataTask` before start receiving data, don't initial `NSURLSessionDataTask` with `dataTaskWithURL: completionHandler`. You should initial the data task with `dataTaskWithURL` and handle the delegate instead.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *urlSession=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]]; 
NSURL *servrurl=[NSURL URLWithString:GetOTP]; 
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask=[urlSession dataTaskWithURL:servrurl];
```

You should add conform to `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` in your delegate file.

In your delegate implementation:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow); // Allow to continue this request
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Receive data");
}
```

Note that you should implement the second delegate method correctly to receive full data of your request, because data will not be received at once.

For more information, refer to this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:

Comment: Tien : i implemented what u pointed way i getting response correctly but how to  share this success response to viewController from NSObject class