# warning message when creating NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using this code to create a NSURLSession but I am getting a warning from Xcode

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

 NSURLSession *fetchTillDataAllv2 = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConf delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
```

The warning is as follows

```
/Users/mdouhan/devnew/NWMobileTill/NWMobileTill/WebServices.m:902:100: Incompatible pointer types sending 'Class' to parameter of type 'id<NSURLSessionDelegate> _Nullable'
```

And it is pointing out that I cannot se delegate; self but how do I correct that?

Answer (score 3):

Likely your code snippet is from a class method (one starting with `+`). Therefore `self` points to a class object.

Typically you solve that problem by creating a shared instance that acts as delegate:

```
+ (id)sharedSessionDelegate // or whatever name, typically the class name
{
  static MyManager *sharedSessionDelegate;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once( &onceToken, 
  ^{
    sharedSessionDelegate = [self new];
  });

  return sharedSessionDelegate;
}
```

Comment: @MattDouhan - You can't. You have to make an instance of that class (e.g. a singleton or plain old instance).

Comment: How do I do that, this is the first time I am running into this

Answer (score -1):

Have you added the delegate in the .h file as follows?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController < NSURLSessionDelegate > {
...
}
```

Comment: @interface WebServices : NSObject <NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate> is what I have

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319616/how-to-call-nsurlsession-delegate-in-nsobject-class-not-in-viewcontroller

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248688/how-to-config-nsurlsessionconfiguration-into-the-nsobject-class

Comment: I am a bit confused I do have the delegates there don't I or what am I missing ?

Comment: The major difference I saw is that you are creating a NSObject with the delegates. On a UIViewController this would have been as simple as adopting the delegates, however if you look at the 2 links, they look into how to config it to a NSObject.

Comment: I looked but I don't get it, I tried a few things but can't get it to work, first time I am trying to do this..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147717/discussion-between-burnie777-and-matt-douhan).